# Query without related objects

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following query:

```
db.Where("user_id = ?", tmpUser.ID).Find(&subscriptions)
```

subscriptions is a slice of the subscription object.

The problem is, it will output all subscriptions include the related objects (like the user object).

How can I query the database and get back only subscription records without the related (belongs to and has many) objects?

Comment: can you share the definition of the subscriptions struct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `auto_preload` setting:

```
db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", false).Where("user_id = ?", tmpUser.ID).Find(&subscriptions)
```

Or you can use the `PRELOAD` struct tag:

```
type Subscription struct {
    ID     uint
    User   User `gorm:"PRELOAD:false"`
    UserID uint
}
```

https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Auto-Preloading

Answer (score 0):

db.Find(&subscriptions). if you want count append .Count(&count) object

Comment: hmm. i would like to have all subscriptions where the user_id is 1 for example and then save the result in a slice of subscriptions. But the problem is, the output also contains all related objects to the subscription, which is for example "User"

Comment: Can you write what you want in a normal SQL statement,  I am quite lost, you say you would like to have all subscriptions but you are worried if the output contains objects related to the subscription

Comment: i want select * from subscriptions where user_id = 1.
type Subscriptions struct {
ID uint
User User
UserID uint
}

type User struct {
ID uint
Name string
}

db.Where("user_id = ?", tmpUser.ID).Find(&subscriptions).Error
 
returns:
all subscriptions from the user, and in each subscrptions the full user object

Comment: you can use "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx", define db tags in json structs, and directly marshal after getting the records. you can ignore the fields in the struct which you dont want and then you can copy only the data you want